# If $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are continuous, and $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for all x in D which is dense in X, then $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for all x.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I'm looking for advice on how to formally prove this:

Given two continuous functions $f_1, f_2 : (X, d_X) \rightarrow (Y, d_Y)$ and assuming that D is dense in X, prove that if $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for all $x \in D$, then $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ for every $x \in X$.

The question makes sense to me; I know I can use the formal definition of continuity and some variation of squeezing any $x \in X$, but I'm not sure exactly how to say that.

Comment: What type of set is $\{x:f_1(x) \neq f_2(x)\}$?

Comment: Because D is dense in X, $\{x:f_1(x) \neq f_2(x)\} = D^c$ would be closed.

Comment: Use continuity to prove that it is open.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, suppose there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $f_1(x_0)\neq f_2(x_0)$. This means that $d_{Y}(f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0))>0$.

Set $\epsilon=d_Y(f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0))$. By continuity of $f_i$ at $x_0$, there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2>0$ such that $\forall x \in X$:

$$d_X(x,x_0)<\delta_1 \implies d_Y(f_1(x),f_1(x_0))<\epsilon/2$$
$$d_X(x,x_0)<\delta_2 \implies d_Y(f_2(x),f_2(x_0)<\epsilon/2.$$
Now take $\delta = \text{min}\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, there exists $z \in D$ such that $d_X(z,x_0)<\delta$.

By hypotesis, we know that $f_1(z)=f_2(z) \iff d_{Y}(f_1(z),f_2(z))=0$. Applying the triangle inequality, we have that
\begin{align} 
d_{Y}(f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0))
&\leq d_Y(f_1(x_0),f_1(z))+d_Y(f_1(z),f_2(z))+d_Y(f_2(z),f_2(x_0)) \\
&=d_Y(f_1(x_0),f_1(z))+d_Y(f_2(z),f_2(x_0)) \\
&<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2 \\
&=\epsilon \\
&= d_Y(f_1(x_0),f_2(x_0))
\end{align}
Which is a contradiction. Thus, $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x \in X$.